# Java Applet/Multiple Class Login

Tags: java, authentication, applet

I am trying to make a Login system, that when I Login, an applet appears. For some reason, it keeps coming up with an error. Here's what I've got:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class login {
private static Scanner luci;

public static void main(String args[]){ 
luci = new Scanner(System.in); 
String idInput;
System.out.println("Please type ID: "); 
idInput = luci.nextLine(); 
String passwordInput; 
System.out.print("Please type Password: "); 
passwordInput = luci.nextLine(); 


if(passwordInput.equals("Atlas") && (idInput.equals("Seymore"))){ 

System.out.println("Authentification complete!"); 

}if(passwordInput.equals("Admin") && (idInput.equals("Admin"))){

     System.out.println("Authentication complete: Reverting To Program.");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(800);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
        loginaccepted objectName = new loginaccepted();
        objectName.paint(null);
}else{
System.out.println("Rong ID or Password!"); 


}
}
}
```

And here is loginaccepted.class:

```
import java.applet.*; 
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class loginaccepted extends Applet{


    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawLine(10, 20, 50, 60 );

    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated. I was just doing this for fun and to help improve my knowledge of the java programming language.

Comment: What is the error you are getting.?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with, this is not how `Applet`s are used, in for that fact, how UI's are used...

You problem stems from the fact that you seem "think" you control the `paint` process...

```
objectName.paint(null);
```

But you are passing a `null` value to the `paint` method.  Apart from the fact that you should never have a need to call `paint` directly, I'm not sure what you expected paint to do...

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawLine(10, 20, 50, 60 );
}
```

`g` is null...

Firstly, forget about applets, seriously, UI's and Swing are complicated enough with adding the complexity of applets to the problem.

Secondly, take a read through [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)...

Swing has it's own mechanisms for getting user input, so you can drop the `Scanner`...